# The Label widget Tkinter cuts off the Long text in the view

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Windows 10 and Anaconda Jupyter Python 3.9.12. I'm trying to build a GUI with one button that randomly picks up a question from an Excel file each time I click on the button. It works fine. But when the question is too long, it just cuts off as in the attached screenshot. I want the line to break, so I can read the whole question and answer it. I tried the wraplength parameter, but it doesn't give me the expected output.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import WORD
import pandas as pd
import random

from textwrap import wrap

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to your Q App")

window.geometry('900x500')

window.config(bg="#F39C12")
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)





lbl = Label(window, text="Q")




df = "Mittagessen: Sie ordern ein Steak, englisch. Der Kellner bringt es durchgebraten. Was tun Sie?"


def random():
    global l2
    global l1
    
    df1 = df
    
    Q = df1
   
    l2.config(text = Q)


btn = Button(window, text="Pick up a question", bg="blue", fg="black", command= random)

btn.grid(column=1, row=5)



l1 = tk.Label(window, text="Please answer",font=("Arial",15),bg="Black",fg="White")

l2 = tk.Label(window, bg="#F73C12",font=("Arial",15), text= "", width=100, justify=CENTER, compound=tk.CENTER)



l2.bind("<Configure>", random)

l2.grid(column=1, row=7)
l1.grid(column=1, row=4)




window.mainloop()
```

Edit: I have put a direct text in the code - df - instead of the Excel file path.

[image]

Comment: what if you remove `wraplength=300` and/or `width=100`? OR maybe your text in Excel has `new lines` and this makes problem.

Comment: maybe better put example text directly in code - so we could simply copy and run code

Comment: `wraplength` is in pixels, so try changing `l2.config(text=Q)` to `l2.config(text=Q, wraplength=l2.winfo_width())`.

Comment: @acw1668 I have tried that modification, but unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: @furas I have removed the `wraplength=300` and the `width=100` but still not effective. I have put direct text to the code, as you asked so it is easier to reproduce.

Comment: The updated code does not match the image.  What is the expected result you want actually?

Comment: I still see `width=100` in code.  And all problem is that `width=100` creates label longer than window but you set `resizable(width=False,height=False)` and it can't resize window to show full label - and finally it looks like it is not centered. maybe you should use `pack()` and `pack(fill="x")` instead of all `grid()`

Comment: on image it looks like you may have spaces at the beginning and at the end - and this moves text in different direction. Maybe you should use `strip()` to remove spaces.

Comment: I tested code with `DataFrame` and `df.sample` also gives problems - it gives you `DataFrame` and when you want to display it then `DataFrame` convert it to string in different way than you expect. Maybe you should get text `Q = df.sample().values[0][0]` without header and row number.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, you are correct. I just updated the code with one sentence, so it reproduciple. I was supposed to update the image, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this resolves it but I see few elements which can make problem.

You use `width=100` which can create label longer than window but `resizable(width=False,height=False)` doesn't allow to resize it to show full label.

But I think main problem it because you get row from `DataFrame` and you send it directly to widget so `DataFrame` converts it to string adding spaces and using `...` to create nice looking table in text console. But this table doesn't have to look nice in GUI. You should get only question from row or format all data in row on your own.

---

Minimal working code with some data in `DataFrame` and I use `df.sample().values[0][1]` to get only question without `header` and row number. Or `df.sample().values[0]` to get row and convert it to string manually.

And later I can use `wrap()` or own method to split to many lines.

I use `pack(fill="x")` instead of `grid()` because it is simpler to resize to full window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import textwrap
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def get_random():
    #Q = df[['type', 'question']].sample().values[0][1]
    #print('Q:', Q)

    row = df[['type', 'question']].sample().values[0]
    print('row:', row)
    Q = '\n'.join(row)
    print('Q:', Q)
    
    # - wrap on length -
    #Q = textwrap.wrap(Q, width=70)
    
    # - wrap on . and : -
    Q = Q.replace('. ', '.\n')#.replace(': ', ':\n')
    
    print('Q:', Q)
    print('---')
    
    question.config(text=Q)

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': [
        'Mittagessen:',
        'Short:',
        'Frage:',
    ],
    'question': [
        'Sie ordern ein Steak, englisch. Der Kellner bringt es durchgebraten. Was tun Sie?',
        'Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Question?',
        'Wie wichtig ist Ihnen unternehmerisches Denken'
    ],
    'answer': [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
    ]
})    

# - gui -

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Welcome to your Q App")
window.geometry('900x500')

window.config(bg="#F39C12")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Pick up a question", bg="blue", fg="black", command=get_random)
btn.pack()

label = tk.Label(window, text="Please answer", font=("Arial",15), bg="black", fg="white")
label.pack()
         
question = tk.Label(window, bg="#F73C12", font=("Arial",15))
question.pack(fill='x')#, padx=25)
         
get_random()         

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the code you pasted. I use it to enhance my code. Moreover, I'm a beginner in that GUI thing, therefore I really appreciate the hints that you shared.